# HTML CSS body autosizing

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I know there's a lot of questions on this type of thing, but I haven't found one that answers my question.
 I have a "news feed" format site where you can filter the posts based on certain criteria. So, with some filters, you get content much taller than the browser window. With other filters, you can get no content.

When I use Webkit's Web Inspector, I see that an `html {min-height:100%}` does the trick for the `<html>` tag. I want the `<body>` to do exactly the same thing: be 100% when the content fits on the page, and expand otherwise.

However, I can't use a percentage `height` or `min-height` on the body when the height isn't set for `<html>`. It doesn't inherit a height to base its percentage off of. So what I end up with when the document has less than a full window of content is everything getting clipped off right and the foot of that content, which screws up my background and stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: and you can't set a height for <html> why?

Comment: Because that would keep it from extending to the bottom of all the content when the content is bigger than the browser window.

Comment: If that happens, then you set the overflow to auto

Comment: If I set overflow:auto on my centered white div, it sort of works... the div itself scrolls instead of the page. I'd rather the whole page just scroll like normal though.

Comment: when you set <html> to height 100% and scroll auto. Then it is like the whole page is scrolling. Or do I miss in the moment something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

From the limited details it sounds like all you need is to add is:

```
html,body{ height: 100%; }
```

And I am guessing that your background is on the body tag.

Comment: Nope, this keeps the heights at the height of the browser window, which is no good when the content extends past one page of the window. The body has a gray background and I have a centered white div where all the content goes. The problem is that div can only be as big as the body.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to set the height of the body to 100%. 100% means, that it should take equally much space as its parent element. So, if your html tag does what it's supposed to, just let the body tag take the same size:

```
<html style="min-height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The body element seems to ignore percentages unless there's a specified height for html, NOT just a min-height.